# Restrict a user input if it contains xyz.co.in as a substring with the help of html5 pattern

Tags: regex, html

I want to disallow user to submit the form if he has xyz.co.in as a substring of his input in a text field say if in an input type text user inserts abc@xyz.co.in123 or abc@xyz.co.in or xyz.co.in123 or xyz.co.in he should not be allowed to submit the form where as if he inputs abc@yxz.co.in he should be allowed to submit the form

my current code is

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <form action="">
            <input type="text" pattern="^(?!.*xyz\.co\.in).*">
            <input type="submit" value="Go" name="Go1">
        </form>
     </body>
</html>
```

but it matches only complete string (xyz.co.in) not the sub strings like abc@xyz.co.in123

Comment: Try removing the `^` which matches the start of the string.

Comment: @Holt could you lease add your comment as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove the `^` at the start of your regexp. `^`  outside any `[]` means "the start of the string", so it won't ever match anything inside the string:

```
> /^abc/.test('abc')
true
> /^abc/.test('aabc')
false
> /abc/.test('aabc')
true
```